# exchange 2013 unable to boot

Tags: windows, exchange, boot

I'm testing Exchange 2013 on a Hyper-V VM with Windows Server 2012 with a couple of problems.

The most important so far is that the VM can't boot windows and when I'm lucky it takes 30 minutes to 1 hour to boot.
After 1 or 2 minutes it stays in a "please wait" screen and the bullets freeze

The server configuration it self is a single virtual core VM with 1024MB of ram (dynamic memory 128MB~2048MB).
It uses a normal 40GB NTFS formatted VHDX hdd

The VM has exchange roles and active directory roles (standalone)

the server is fully updated

This problem occurs since the first reboot after installing exchange.

There is a change in the normal configuration, I've installed a custom SSL cert on the *:443 IIS default web site.

I hope somebody here can help me.

Regards

Comment: Memory - Varies depending on Exchange roles that are installed: Mailbox - 8GB minimum; Client Access - 4GB minimum; Mailbox and Client Access combined - 8GB minimum. Using dynamic memory features for Exchange isn't supported. - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996719(v=exchg.150).aspx - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj619301(v=exchg.150).aspx#BKMK_ExchangeMemory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to bump up the vRAM to at least **4GB**.

- [Exchange 2013 System Requirements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996719.aspx)

  - Mailbox Role: **8GB** minimum
  - Client Access Role: **4GB** minimum
  - Mailbox/Client Access Roles combined: **8GB** minimum

I'm also testing Exchange 2013 (w/ combined MB/CAS roles) on Windows Server 2012. The following measurements should give you an idea of what the RAM usage looks like on a freshly booted instance w/ 5GB of vRAM. The boot process takes about 4 minutes on my configuration.

**Exchange Server Profile**

```
[PS] Get-ExchangeServer | fl AdminDisplayVersion,ServerRole
```

```
AdminDisplayVersion : Version 15.0 (Build 516.32)
ServerRole          : Mailbox, ClientAccess
```

**OS Profile**

```
[PS] Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem | fl Caption,NumberOfProcesses,TotalVisibleMemorySize,FreePhysicalMemory
```

```
Caption                : Microsoft Windows Server 2012 Datacenter
NumberOfProcesses      : 90
TotalVisibleMemorySize : 5242356
FreePhysicalMemory     : 1074148
```

**Top 10 Processes Sorted by RAM (Working Set) Usage**

`[PS] ps | sort ws -desc | select -first 10`

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
    766      85   449588     392864  1577    30.76   5872 Microsoft.Exchange.Store.Worker
   2032     205   285476     317536 -1742    49.19   3040 noderunner
   3083     205   225556     293404  1211    31.81   3228 MSExchangeHMWorker
   1500     154   228192     292964  1017    37.03   7848 w3wp
   1056     144   202968     250932   974    20.37   9140 w3wp
   1276     102   182708     227184   908    29.05   5380 w3wp
   1339     115   186792     226348   938    28.59   7108 w3wp
   1240      89   178648     179116  1528     7.39   1096 EdgeTransport
   1201      97   138584     174724   858    17.96   7300 w3wp
   1717      80   126228     166900   908    10.75   3664 MSExchangeMailboxAssistants
```

Comment: H'm so that happens when exchange can't use the minimum amount of ram.

the server booted up in about 3-4 minutes.

The host server it self has 8GB of ram, so I think I need to upgrade it...